# Inaccurate column separation on string data containing commas in CSV file in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: python-3.x, azure-machine-learning-service, kaggle, email-parsing

I'm using first 100 of lines from [The Enron Email Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/wcukierski/enron-email-dataset/home) for my experiment in Azure ML Studio, however the Saved Dataset object is being populated with odd 4.8K lines instead of 100. That must be due to ["Inaccurate column separation on string data containing commas"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/convert-to-csv#inaccurate-column-separation-on-string-data-containing-commas) issue, which I understand.

However, using same dataset in the Python project locally and/or in Azure ML Jupyter notebook (same imported dataset from ML Studio - not separately imported to Jupyter notebook) the number of lines is being read correctly and the further logic does also work fine.

Jupyter example:

```
from azureml import Workspace
ws = Workspace()
ds = ws.datasets['The Enron Email Dataset (Minimal)']
emails_df = ds.to_dataframe()
```

Local example:

```
import pandas as pd
emails_df = pd.read_csv('C:/enron-email-dataset/emails.csv', nrows=100)
```

And here is how dataset visualisation looks like in Azure ML Studio 
[image]

It's clear that it get's messed up after it gets moved from saved datasets to an experiment, but my question is - what would be the best way to work around it? Calling dataset from Azure BLOB Storage inside my Python code perhaps?

**EDIT 1:** Removing commas from CSV file didn't helped either. The dataset is working fine in Jupyter and locally, but it appears messed up when added to the experiment.

**EDIT 2:** Removing carriage returns resulted in dataset being visualised correctly in the experiment, however that broke the further text pre-processing logic in Python code ([email.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html)). Which I could amend making it to work across different environments. That's probably as good as it can get.
[image]